# Use pseudo-classes with imported stylesheet as CSS module

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-modules

I use React in combination with TypeScript, I have a separate CSS file for each component. I import my CSS file as follows:

```
import styles from 'pages/login/Login.module.css'
```

Assigning a className looks like that:

```
<input className={styles.username} ref={nameRef} type="text"  placeholder="USERNAME"/>
```

Is there an option to use pseudo-classes?

```
<input className={styles.username:active} ref={nameRef} type="text"  placeholder="USERNAME"/>
```

This approach obviously does not work, it is just to make it clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe consider using `active` as a conditional to apply appropriate styling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you apply a `className`, all pseudo-selectors defined in the stylesheet for that CSS class [should automatically apply](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/pseudo-class-selectors.md) as well.

> Because css modules works by adding classes to your elements you can easily add pseudo class selectors.

```css
/* component/text.css */
.text {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 24px;
}
.text:hover {
  color: #f60;
}
```

```
/* component/text.jsx */
import styles from './text.css';

<p className={ styles.text }>Text with hover</p>
```

Unfortunately, we cannot apply them one by one.